# Verify Cades-Bes signature

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle, x509, verification

I created with java and bouncy castle an electronic signature in Cades-Bes formats. Do you have any idea if just using bouncy castle can generate a class that makes the verification of this signature is that whether we can extend the class of verification cms signing that is what we have to add ...?

My verification code must check

- The signing of Validity
- Certificate Validity Period (Check from x509 certificate)
- Certification String (Check from x509 certificate)
- Control of absence from the CRL (Check from x509 certificate)
- The elements E, CN, OU, O: (Check from x509 certificate)

Comment: Your question sounds somewhat confused. Anyways you should be aware that the exact verification routine can depend on the legal context of the signature and, therefore, there may not be an existing verification class for your use case.

Comment: you mean I can not develop a java application to check the validation of a file signed in Cades-bes formats ??

Comment: Of course you can as long as you are aware of the legal requirements.  I merely say that there might not be a ready-made solution for you.

Comment: thanks @mkl for your answer but can you more explain for me
i create a java class with bouncy castle witch can verify the cms signature . is it able to do this for Cades-bes signature?

Comment: What I mean is that depending on the kind of signature and the kind of desired verification result some tests may or may not be required. E.g. some kinds may require OCSP tests for all non-root certificates in the chain while others may be content with an OCSP test of the end entity; some kinds may allow you to believe in signing time attribute values while others may require validated time stamps; the allowed algorithms may differ substantially; etc pp. You can usually execute all those tests using the appropriate BC classes but you may have quite some orchestration of tests to do.

Comment: Do you know  a free tool that allows me to check my cades-bes signature is valid or not ??

Comment: *check my cades-bes signature is valid or not* - ***Valid* in which context?** As mentioned above, verification requirements may differ in different contexts. A signature valid in one context might not be valid in another.

Comment: i mean my cades-bes satisfies it the legal requirements for electronic signatures, as defined in the European Directive on Electronic Signatures?  provides it basic authentication and integrity protection?

Comment: *my cades-bes satisfies it the legal requirements* - that's what you **claim** but the verification code you want has to **prove** it. So, what are the verification requirements?

Comment: my verification code must check
- The signing of Validity
- Certificate Validity Period (Check from x509 certificate)
- Certification String (Check from x509 certificate)
- Control of absence from the CRL (Check from x509 certificate)
- The elements E, CN, OU, O: (Check from x509 certificate)

Comment: Ok; I added those required checks to your question and added some relevant tags.

Comment: @lolla download https://github.com/esig/dss project. There is a implementation of CAdES-BES validation (and other types) using BC.